# Un utilisateur non enregistré peut-il éditer des questions ou réponses ?

Tags: support

En parcourant les questions aujourd'hui, j'ai vu plusieurs questions marquées modifiées par [TheSwagSoul](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/7779/theswagsoul), avec une réputation de 1.

[image]

En ouvrant lesdites questions, je n'ai pas trouvé les modifications en question. Rien ne figure non plus dans les files de *review*.

Enfin, le profil de l'utilisateur comporte la mention *Unregistered*, alors qu'il semble bien associé à un compte fr.SX (le seul compte SX figurant sur son profil, par ailleurs).

Google ne semble pas avoir d'historique de cet utilisateur sur SX.

Bref, je ne comprends pas cette information. Est-elle normale ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

L'utilisateur a ajouté trois réponses similaires contenant un lien vers un site sans rapport avec les questions, s'apparentant à du spam… Je les ai supprimées, et elles ne sont donc plus visibles aux utilisateurs n'ayant pas le privilège « access to moderation tools » (obtenu après 2000 points de réputation sur un site en béta).

Je suis d'accord que l'affichage « modified » sur la page principale est assez  perturbant. Peut-être serait-il mieux dans ce cas de ne rien afficher du tout.

Comment: Merci pour l'information et désolé pour la question qui peut paraître sans intérêt, mais cela me laissait perplexe.

Comment: @Chop http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120326/unbump-a-question-if-the-answer-providing-the-bump-is-deleted